# Tmux not setting $HOME

Tags: ubuntu, sudo, environment-variables, tmux

I noticed a difference in tmux behavior switching from Debian to Ubuntu.

Expected / old behavior set the $HOME (and all kind of related settings) according to the user starting the tmux instance:

```
$ echo $HOME
/home/tacov

$ sudo tmux
# echo $HOME
/root
# exit

$ sudo -unachov tmux
$ echo $HOME
/home/nachov
```

Undesired / new behavior does not set $HOME:

```
$ echo $HOME
/home/tacov

$ sudo tmux
# echo $HOME
/home/tacov
# exit

$ sudo -unachov tmux
$ echo $HOME
/home/tacov
```

.profile and such files get loaded from the incorrect $HOME, so I don't think the solution lies there. The home directories are set correctly:

```
$ egrep 'tacov|root' /etc/passwd
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
tacov:x:1000:1000:TacoV,,,:/home/tacov:/bin/bash
```

What should I adjust to regain the old behavior?

Comment: Check the sudo man page; I believe there is an option to set or not set the environment.  On mobile now or I would write a full answer.

Comment: I think you're looking for the -H option.

Comment: I see, so nothing to do with tmux really, which explains the lack of search hits. Thanks - will try and report back.

Comment: If you need more than just `$HOME`, try `sudo -i` which runs the new shell as login shell.

Comment: Both -i and -H have the desired result (both leading eg to .profile being read). On a side note, in /etc/sudoers the env_reset is set, so I do not understand why the options are needed in the first place. If someone posts a full answer I can accept it, otherwise should I self-answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments:

The difference is in the settings of `sudo`, it has nothing to do with `tmux`.

If you provide the option `-i` or `-H`, the `.profile` is read and it works as expected again, `$HOME` is set.

From `man sudo`:

```
 -H, --set-home
             Request that the security policy set the HOME environment
             variable to the home directory specified by the target user's
             password database entry.  Depending on the policy, this may
             be the default behavior.

 -i, --login
             Run the shell specified by the target user's password data‐
             base entry as a login shell.  This means that login-specific
             resource files such as .profile, .bash_profile or .login will
             be read by the shell.  If a command is specified, it is
             passed to the shell for execution via the shell's -c option.
             If no command is specified, an interactive shell is executed.
             sudo attempts to change to that user's home directory before
             running the shell.  The command is run with an environment
             similar to the one a user would receive at log in.  Note that
             most shells behave differently when a command is specified as
             compared to an interactive session; consult the shell's man‐
             ual for details.  The Command environment section in the
             sudoers(5) manual documents how the -i option affects the en‐
             vironment in which a command is run when the sudoers policy
             is in use.
```